# How get a higher resolution icon for Google Chrome in Docky?

Tags: icons, docky, google-chrome

I have a great icon pack and nearly every single app has a high resolution icon. But not Google Chrome. In Docky the Google Chrome icon is fuzzy and bad, how can I replace it with a high resolution one?

Comment: Which icon theme are you using? What is the icon size setting in docky?

Comment: Did you just install Google Chrome, or has it been installed? If you just installed it, you may need to log out and then log back in.

Comment: @russjr08 sure enough, upon starting up this morning the high-res one from my graphics pack is there!

Comment: @DoR this one, is amazing and has icons for pretty much everything even windows extentions: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Faenza?content=128143

Comment: @Shogun glad to here it worked!

Comment: @Shogun Please add an answer with your solution and accept it as the answer so the solution doesn't get lost in the comments, thanks!

Comment: @JorgeCastro done, was giving him a chance to post the answer for the karma but I just posted one for the sake of this resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Did you just install Google Chrome, or has it been installed? If you just installed it, you may need to log out and then log back in." -from user via comments: https://askubuntu.com/users/2733/russjr08

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use chromium (in the repositories since maverick, available in a ppa else). It's the same than google chrome (same features, extensions...), but without the "Google is spying you" part. And the icon in docky is just perfect!