# Google Chrome icon is fuzzy/blurry in Docky

Tags: unity, 14.04, google-chrome, icons, docky

As the question says, the Chrome icon is fuzzy in docky.
I tried this:
[How get a higher resolution icon for Google Chrome in Docky?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10134/how-get-a-higher-resolution-icon-for-google-chrome-in-docky)

But that didn't seem to help. I would have commented my issue there, but I need rep. points for that.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into this problem myself. I fixed it by editing the google-chrome.desktop file found in /usr/share/applications

```
sudo vi /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

You'll find a line

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
```

I changed mine to

```
Exec=google-chrome %U
```

After restarting Google Chrome the icon was all shiny and nice :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Totally worked! @BarryG Thanks! :D
Had to use gedit under sudo from terminal to edit it, cuz double clicking it opens it as some window.
Also, can't upvote it. Damn rep. system. -_-

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned using sudo. Happy to help!